# Break down each period of a signal

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, numerical-integration

I have an experimental bench where I retrieve data of the power of a compressor.
I import the csv using python and pandas. So it's a pandas dataframe with index datetime and a float column with P_comp.

And I would like to define and calculate the area under the curve for each period like this : 
[image]

For the moment, I do it manually which is really annoying, I'm plotting all the data and manually selecting a range where there is a periodic steady state and then I'm integrating P_comp using np.trapz on this range.

I tried scipy.signal but I’m not sure it’s a good tool to do this job. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: please add what you have tried, also share the function of this signal

Comment: What is your input format? is it data or image?

Comment: Add your code to the post, so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the intervals are fairly regular and the low-values are almost equal, too, so you might get away with taking the first value below a defined threshold, and then after a period of time the next etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I found the solution using scipy.signal.find_peaks and numpy diff